# Partial indexing in Apache Solr 7.3.1

Tags: apache, indexing, solr

I am using solr 7.3.1 for indexing documents. Right now it's indexing every documents in the referred location(which is quite large close to 1 TB). It 
takes 3-4 days to index the entire folder. And the documents keep getting edited, added, deleted every hour. What is the best approach to keep the solr index updated ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a small application that listens to file system events inside the document hierarchy where the documents are stored.

That way you can send the documents to Solr as soon as they're written to disk. Exactly how you do that will depend on your operating system and what languages you can write code in. There's hooks for `inotify` under Linux that you can use through `inotifywait` and `bash`, or you can use `inotify` as [a python module](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/).

That way you can index any updated document as soon it has been written to the disk, and you can do this while the regular, initial indexing operation runs.

However, if *every* document changes each hour (meaning you have to index every single document within the hour, each hour), you'll have to scale your infrastructure to be able to index the content as fast as possible within the hour, but exactly how to do that will depend on many factors (such as document types, available libraries, other limitations in the project, etc.), and is probably outside of what can be decently answered here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @MatsLindh. One thing to clarify -

In my system not every document gets updated every hour. 
So can solr indexing be automated in such a way that if the last updated date of a particular file is greater than the solr indexing timestamp of the same file then solr will delete the file from previous index and then will reindex it otherwise it will skip to the next file ?

Comment: You'll have to write logic to handle that yourself, but that's a possibility, sure. I'd probably still try to see if you can use inotifywait or something similar, as that would be even more efficient.

Comment: I am on windows and using c#. The files are in a windows PC folder mapped though a network drive on our LAN. So most probably I will have to use something close to FileSystemWatcher to track changes in that mapped directory. But the question is does solr have any api to allow that kind of automated conditional indexing ??? As far as I have gone through their official documentation I've not found anything yet. If you can guide me on that one it would be very helpful

Comment: No, you'll have to write that application yourself.